# Moving multiple points in batch using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, arcgis-10.5, batch, spatial-analysis

I have multiple parcel polygons and they all have one side touching the lake polygon. Each parcel polygon has a point inside which is now at the centroid of the parcel. I need to find a way to move the points in batch so they remain inside the parcel polygon while the points would move at a specific distance from the edge of the lake, or on the edge of the lake.

Here how my data is looking actually. I need to move the red point to the edge of the lake or to a specific distance from the edge of the lake while the points remain inside of the parcel polygon that they are actually in.

I have access to all levels of licence depending of my actual needs.

[actual data](https://www.flickr.com/photos/107165482@N04/46753526681/in/dateposted-public/)

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing what you want to do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which ArcGIS license level you're running, and, whether you would be open to a solution that retains your centroids and creates a second set of points at 2m?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to post my printscreen. Dragging it from my computer doesn't work, so I'm in the processs of trying to clear my flickr account so I can upload it there...

Comment: Interesting problem. It'd be possible using arcpy and geometry operations.Not sure if you want to explore that avenue? Off the top of my head I can't think of any combination of tools that'd move your points to where you want.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in exploring all avenues to solve this!

Comment: Please use the Picture button to include pictures. Potential answerers will not always follow links.

Comment: I tried to post the picture with the picture button, but it's not working, the image don't show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will create a second set of points while retaining the original centroids. It requires an Advanced license.

1. [Buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) the lake by 2m, or other specified distance.
2. Use the [Polygon to Line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/polygon-to-line.htm) tool to convert the buffer polygon to a line feature.
3. [Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/coverage-toolbox/intersect.htm) the buffer line feature with the original parcels.
4. Use the [Feature to Point](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-point.htm) tool to generate centroid points along the buffer line. Choosing the **Inside** option will ensure that the points fall on the line (otherwise, they could fall inside or outside of a buffer line if the line was curved).

Comment: And then I completed the operation by exporting the attribute table of the original centroid, added the table to the project and joined the table to the layer containing the new points.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will create a second set of points while retaining the original centroids. It requires an Advanced license.

1. [Buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) the lake by 2m, or other specified distance.
2. Use the [Near](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) tool between the centroids and the lake buffer. Choose the option to add **Location**. This will add **NEAR_X** and **NEAR_Y** fields to the centroids indicating the X,Y position on the lake buffer closest to the original centroid.
3. Make an [XY Event Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) from the centroids, using NEAR_X and NEAR_Y as the X and Y inputs to the tool. The resulting points will be the closest points falling on the 2m buffer.
4. Export the event layer to a feature class, if so desired.

Comment: I think this could fail in cases for parcels whose sides obliquely intersect the shoreline. The point could end up in the neighboring parcel.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall that's a good point. I've posted an alternate answer with an approach based on intersecting the buffer (line) with the parcel boundaries.